# Funky Alien Band in 80s Sci-fi Series: Identify Show & Episode

Tags: story-identification

I have vague recollections of an alien band playing their futuristic funky music in a late 70s to mid 80s sci-fi series. Their instruments of course were not traditional and were of the futuristic type. The series may have been Battlestar Galactica, Buck Rogers, or a similar show. There is little else that I recall from popular sci-fi series then, but this vague memory has persisted, and any assistance resolving it is appreciated.

Comment: Was this series cartoon or live-action?

Comment: A couple of additional possibilities are that it was the Star Wars Holiday Special (which featured a few musical acts), or the Daft Punk anime Interstella 5555 (which was made in the 2000s but with a very old-school anime style).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly, the Buck Rogers episode [Space Rockers](https://buckrogers.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Rockers)?

> Buck becomes involved with a futuristic rock group named Andromeda when a series of riots break out at all of their concerts. Buck's investigation finds that the band's manager, Lars Mangros, has been secretly encoding the group's music with behavior-altering sounds that create the riots. Buck is forced to convince Andromeda not to play at galactic-wide broadcast from the space station Musicworld, to prevent Mangros from causing chaos throughout the galaxy.

[image]

Comment: The plexiglass pegs in the bar-like structures they are "playing" confirm this is the one.

Answer (score 0):

In the first *Battlestar Galactica*  episode "Saga of a Star World" September 17, 1978, the survivors of the 12 colonies flee and stop for fuel and rest at the planet Carillon.  In a casino Starbucks meets an singing trio.

The singers are definitely not humans:

https://bwmedia.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/image6.jpg[1](https://bwmedia.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/image6.jpg)

So you might remember the alien singing Trio from the *Battlestar Galactica* episode "Saga of a Star World", September 17, 1978, or the band from the *Buck Rogers* episode "Space Rockers", February 21, 1980, mentioned in Moriarty's answer, or possibly both of them.

Other science fiction shows from the 1970s that might have had alien bands include:

*Space 1999* (1975-77)

*Quark* (1977-78)

*Blake's 7* (1978-81)

*Jason of Star Command* (1978-81)

But I don't specifically remember any episodes with alien bands in those shows.